# Get all attributes from xml and save to dictionary

Tags: c#

I have XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
    <methods MethodName = 'GetCube'   ksp = '5' typreln = 'value'  periodtype = 'value' />
    <methods MethodName = 'MymethodName'   ksp = '5' periodtype = 'value' />
</appSettings>
```

Now I need to get all attributes from the XML and save it to a dictionary like this:

> MethodName - GetCube
>   ksp - 5
>   typreln - value

Comment: Is a Dictionary really what you're looking for? Because in your case you'll end up having duplicates (not allowed), since you have many methods elements.

Comment: I want something, what i can use like dictionary: key > value.

Comment: I am writing console application, which invokes asmx web methods without adding Web Reference.  I need to get web method names and paremeters from XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have them in AppSettings section: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can i add attributes except  key - value, because config file also must have method names, web service url, web service namespaces